# WebMethod via Ajax Exception: Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, http

I am trying to write out an Excel .xls file from Internet Explorer. One way, that is working, is to have an asp:ImageButton's click event do the job. It is this:

```
    protected void imgExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = list; // assume this has my data
        gv.DataBind();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=RoamingPartners.xls");

        StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(swriter);

        gv.RenderControl(hwriter);

        Response.Write(swriter.ToString().Replace("&lt;br/&gt;", " "));
        swriter.Close();
        hwriter.Close();
        Response.End();
    }
```

As stated, this works, and writes out my file.

However, I don't want to use an asp server control. Instead, I turn the above into a WebMethod and make an ajax call via jQuery. Note that this
is similar to the above method, except I must use HttpContext.Current.Response instead of Response:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void ExportData()
    {

        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = list; // assume this has my data (I use country param to get it)
        gv.DataBind(); 

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=RoamingPartners.xls");

        StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(swriter);

        gv.RenderControl(hwriter);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(swriter.ToString().Replace("&lt;br/&gt;", " "));
        swriter.Close();
        hwriter.Close();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

For good measure, my ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/ExportData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
```

The problem is that this throws a "Thread was being aborted." exception. Someone suggested catching the exception, but I still did not get my file.
Another suggestion was to use HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() instead of HttpContext.Current.Response.End(), but this also doesn't write out the file. How do I get this to work?

Comment: A WebMethod does not have control of the current response stream, so this is not possible to do this way.

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand this. A web method is for the web. The web uses http. Why don't I have control?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086999/download-file-from-c-sharp-through-web-method-via-ajax-call

Comment: Most helpful. Thanks.